# Do you need to perform variables reduction for tree-based models?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, boosting

I know for methods and linear regression, GLM, Logistic regression, we typically run through a lot of variable reduction methods, i.e, forward/backward/stepwise, univariate analysis; variable importance through RF, GBM.

I know include too many features in linear model lead to overfitting, but I don't know if this is true for tree-based models.

I noticed this while I was building a GLM for a company project and through it might be a good idea to build a GBM and compare both.

Does tree-based models like RF and GMB, Catboost require you to drop variables in order to achieve a good model? - Re-build model many times eventually with a small model with fewer variables.

Comment: In simply, in GLM I can start with a data set with 3000+ variables, eventually the goal is to have ~15 variables model and I had to keep dropping variables along the way. Does the same apply to Ensemble method tree-models?